# Слайдер для большого количества фотографий

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Здравствуйте. Подскажите адаптивный кроссбраузерный слайдер с превьюшками (одна большая картинка, под ней несколько маленьких) для большого количества фотографий (больше 200).

Насколько я понимаю большинство слайдов (например slick) создают трэк со всех картинок, а при циклической прокрутке в конец и начало добавляют ещё несколько слайдов. Соответственно при перелистывании пересчитывается положение всех слайдов, а так как их много, это создаёт очень большую нагрузку...
По идеи Нужен слайдер по типу скамейки запасных, т.е в трэк добавляются те, которые активны + следующий и предыдущий (возможно по 2-3), а остальные картинки даже не загружаются (возможно по типу lazy load). при перелистывании проходит автоматическая перегенерация трэка.....

Есть ли готовые такие решения или возможно какой-то другой вариант не ресурсоемкий...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unite Gallery](http://unitegallery.net/)

[По вашему описанию](http://cms.unitegallery.net/index.php?page=default)

На данный момент везет 992 фото у меня.

[Гитхаб](https://github.com/vvvmax/unitegallery)